# Unable to run Vagrant commands through PowerShell script in VirtualBox

Tags: powershell, vagrant, virtualbox

I try to run these 2 commands in the end of big script in Windows 10 which is installed in VirtualBox:

```
#Navigate to folder where Vagrant file will be placed

CD "D:\VagrantBoxes\Win8"

#mount Windows box

vagrant init windows_81x64-enterprise_virtualbox_15.07.17.box

#run Vagrant

vagrant up
```

But I receive an error:

```
vagrant : The term 'vagrant' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,  function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At F:\Scripts\Install_Vagrant.ps1:3 char:1
+ vagrant up
+ ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (vagrant:String) [],   CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

But I can run these commands via PowerShell and PowerShell ISE severally. Also, I don't know why, PowerShell is executed Vagrant commands with comment lines.

Comment: vagrant is probably not in the path. Just write `$env:path -split ';'` and check whether the vagrant bin directory is there

Comment: Martin, here is an output

PS C:\VagrantBoxes\Win8> $env:path -split ';'
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin

C:\PROGRA~2\Oracle\VirtualBox

So yes, Vagrant bin is there.

Comment: Martin, it work! Thanks again - PowerShell God!

Comment: How did you solve it? was was the issue?

Comment: Yes, the problem was in .exe file extension. So you need add .exe after each Vagrant commands.

Comment: Okay, so I added an answer and will delete my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace `vagrant` with `vagrant.exe`

Comment: Yes, the problem was in .exe file extension. So you need add .exe after each Vagrant commands.